# Need help in iterating and changing index using dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, while-loop

So basically what i am trying to achieve is get my program to perform a n number of iterations on one input variable(i use a for loop for this). After the for loop ends the program asks the user if they want to continue, for yes the program then asks the user for another n number of iterations to perform on the same input variable. The program then has to start the operation from where it left from the previous value, i used a dictionary for this but cant find it working. Would be great if i can get some help.
my code is pasted below:

```py
def function(x, i):
    return x**i


num_dic = {}
j = 1

while True:
    if j == 1:
        start = 1
        n = int(input("number of iterations: "))
        x = int(input("Number to perform operation: "))
        for i in range(start, n + 1):
            total = function(x, i)
            print(f"{x}", "**", i, "=", total)
            num_dic[f"{i}"] = total

    elif j > 1:
        start = int(sorted(num_dic.keys())[-1]) + 1
        x = sorted(num_dic.values())[-1]
        n = int(input("number of iterations: "))
        for i in range(start, n + 1):
            total = function(x, i)
            print(f"{x}", "**", i, "=", total)
            num_dic[f"{i}"] = total
    j += 1
    while True:  # while loop for repeating program
        ask = input("Do you want to continue?(Y to continue/ N to exit): ")
        if ask.upper() == "Y":
            break

        if ask.upper() == "N":
            break
        else:
            print("Please enter a correct operation (Y/N) ")
            continue
    if ask.upper() == "Y":
        continue
    else:
        break
```

current output i am getting:

```
number of iterations: 5
Number to perform operation: 2
2 ** 1 = 2
2 ** 2 = 4
2 ** 3 = 8
2 ** 4 = 16
2 ** 5 = 32
Do you want to continue?(Y to continue/ N to exit): y
number of iterations: 5
```

after this part it just doesn't do anything.

the desired output should look like:

```
number of iterations: 5
Number to perform operation: 2
2 ** 1 = 2
2 ** 2 = 4
2 ** 3 = 8
2 ** 4 = 16
2 ** 5 = 32
Do you want to continue?(Y to continue/ N to exit): y
number of iterations: 5
2 ** 6 = 64
2 ** 7 = 128
2 ** 8 = 256
2 ** 9 = 512
2 ** 10 = 1024
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a dictionary for this operation. You just need a clean and proper while-loop that can keep track of your variables, specifically the `exponent` (variable `j` in your original code) and your number of iterations, `n`.

`base` doesn't change, so it should be left outside the while-loop, as advised by the @Blckknght's answer to this question.

```py
exponent = 1
base = int(input("Number to perform operation: "))
n = None  # initialize n to None

while True:
    # logic to keep track of n in the previous loop, if there is one.
    if n:
        n += int(input("number of iterations: "))  # cumulatively increment n if user wishes to continue.
    else:
        n = int(input("number of iterations: "))

    # while-loop that prints the output for a single set of x and n values
    while n >= j:
        print(f"{base} ** {exponent} = {base ** exponent}")
        exponent += 1

    # get user input for continuation
    ask = input("Do you want to continue?(Y/ N): ")

    # while loop to handle user input values
    while ask.upper() not in ["Y", "N"]:
        ask = input("Please enter a correct operation (Y/N).")
    
    if ask.upper() == 'Y':
        continue  # loop back to the outer while-loop and ask for another set of user input
    elif ask.upper() == 'N':
        break  # break if user says no
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you only need to keep track of where you left off, there's no need to store many values in a dictionary. Just remembering the base and the last exponent used is enough. And conveniently, the variables `x` and `i` that you're using won't automatically get reset between iterations, so you can just start the next iteration from `i + 1`:

```
elif j > 1:
    n = int(input("number of iterations: "))
    for i in range(i+1, i + n + 1):
        total = function(x, i)
        print(f"{x}", "**", i, "=", total)
```

Indeed, you could probably simplify things so that you don't need a special case for the first iteration. Just ask for the base before the loop starts! Here's how I'd do it (using more descriptive variable names too):

```
base = int(input("Number to perform operation: "))
start_from = 1
while True:
    n = int(input("number of iterations: "))
    for exponent in range(start_from, start_from + n):
        print(f'{base} ** {exponent} = {function(base, exponent)}')
    start_from = start_from + n

    # ask about continuing down here, optionally break out
```

If you really want to prompt for the number of iterations first, before asking for the base, you could probably make that work by using a sentinel value like `None` to indicate when it hasn't been set yet, so that you only prompt for it the first iteration (without explicitly counting):

```
base = None
start_from = 0
while True:
    n = int(input("number of iterations: "))
    if base is None:
        base = int(input("Number to perform operation: "))
    # ...
```